# Strange row numbers in filtering R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a field `isEOD`. I have `rbind` dataframes for every day with each daily dataframe having last row's `isEOD` set as 1.

However I get the output below:

```
    > head( data [ data$isEOD, c('date','isEOD') ] )
              date isEOD
    208   20190226     0
    208.1 20190226     0
    208.2 20190226     0
    208.3 20190226     0
    208.4 20190226     0
    208.5 20190226     0
```

1. Why are the row numbers 208.X ?
2. When I have filtered on isEOD, then why is it 0 on the returned rows?

Comment: The rownames are a result of your subsetting. Try it with `iris`, i.e. `head(iris[iris$Species, c('Petal.Length', 'Species')])`...not sure what you are trying to do here. Now for returning 0 on rows...no idea. I need to see the process you followed. Also please edit to include reproducible example and your expected output

Comment: @Sotos Thanks! I modified my command to `> head( data [ data$isEOD == 1, c('date','isEOD') ] )`, and now it works as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably what you need is

```
data[data$isEOD == 1, c('date','isEOD')]
```

To understand what is happening here, consider this reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), b = 1:5, c = 2:6)
df[df$a, c("b", "c")]

#    b c
#1   1 2
#1.1 1 2
#1.2 1 2
```

As there are three 1's in column `a`, row number 1 is subsetted 3 times and since R cannot have duplicate row names it adds postfix `.1`, `.2` to rownames. . However, if you do

```
df[df$a == 1, c("b", "c")]

#  b c
#1 1 2
#3 3 4
#4 4 5
```

you get the expected output.